# ASP.NET MVC 5 Need help working with data

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database

everyone,
right now I've got 2 tables

> Table A with cols

```
match_1, match_2, match_3, match_4, match_5,
    [row1]1      , 3      , 5      , 7,     , 9
    [row2]1      , 4
    [row3]2      , 4      , 6      , 8
    [row4]3      , 5      , 7
```

> Table B with col

```
winning_team
    [row1]1
    [row2]4
    [row3]6
    [row4]8
```

How do I go about writing code to display a view with the winning team(numbers) being highlighted?

Comment: You really have a separate column for each match: that makes it much harder. Also Table B has a list of wining teams (fine), but no indication about which match (in SQL table rows are *unordered* you cannot assume the order rows are saved will be the order they come back). As things stand there is no way to associate a winning team with a specific match.

Comment: Does Table A contains the winning team id's !!

Comment: Hi, Richard, thank you for your prompt reply.

*update

Table B also consists of
session_id
team_id_1
team_id_2

winning_team will be either team_id_1/team_id_2

Basically, 1 session consists of many matches
and team_id_1 & team_id_2 are unique in Table A

Is there any solution if that's the case?

Comment: Thanks Sudhanshu, it doesn't, it will be retrieved from Table B.

Comment: *1 session consists of many matches and team_id_1 & team_id_2 are unique in Table B.

Comment: Each row in Table A is a session !!